# What introducing phonology book cover its applications on poetics or musicology?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, resource-request, poetry

I am an absolute beginner with basic knowledge on linguistics, phonetics, phonology, poetics or musicology acquired by reading from Wikipedia, and currently attending a short course to learn to use the IPA chart. Despite the practical motivations to pronounce English words correctly, the way sounds, tones and rhythms interacting and resonating with our mind and psychology really fascinates me. I know poetics and musicology may largely be out of linguists' scope, but since phonetics is essential for these fields, I think it is appropriate to ask about its theory and applications here.

Do you know any good introductory book on phonetics, preferably with its applications in poetics or musicology? I have a physics background.

Comment: You might be interested in searching articles on "sound symbolism" (also "phonosemantics", "ideophones" etc.)

Comment: Do I need to have some elementary knowledge on linguistics first?

Comment: Just search around for articles and introductions. Some of it will be specialized, but if you gloss over that, a lot is accessible without prior knowledge.  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism) is as good start as any.

Comment: I have to point out that phonetics is probably the most non-essential aspect of linguistics for the study of music and poetry. Phonology is more important (as well as syntax and semantics). There are practical phonetic considerations for sopranos, w.r.t. vowel identification, which is kind of comprehensible from a phonetic perspective but is really in the realm of musical acoustics. I assume you're familiar with Lehrahl and Jackendoff. Laura Dilley did some work on phonology and music, but this isn't stuff that would go in any intro textbook.